# Getting issues when making multipart/form-data request in jmeter

Tags: django, testing, jmeter, load-testing

I'm getting issues when making multipart/form-data request in jmeter.
I am  getting status code 201,
but when downloading it showing unsupported format.

```
--AaB03x
content-disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="strawberryamp_kiwi.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

D:\appointy\strawberryamp_kiwi.jpg





--AaB03x
content-disposition: form-data; name="file_type"

IMAGE
--AaB03x
content-disposition: form-data; name="is_public"

true
--AaB03x
content-disposition: form-data; name="owner"

"48a74388-6f29-45d2-b2fc-b6b27d64f4e0"
--AaB03x--
```

On postman everything is working fine, but not on jmeter.

I'm expecting proper
downloading after sending the file.

Answer (score 0):

Given "On postman everything is working fine" you can just record your request using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder.](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)

1. [Start JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)
2. [Import JMeter's certificate into Postman](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/certificates/)

   [image]
3. [Configure Postman to use JMeter as the proxy](https://learning.postman.com/docs/getting-started/proxy/)

   [image]
4. Copy the file you're going to upload to "bin" folder of your JMeter installation.
5. Run your request in Postman.
6. JMeter should generate proper [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) and you should be able to replay the request successfully

More information: [How to Convert Your Postman API Tests to JMeter for Scaling](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/convert-postman-api-tests)